# Combination of two column names from a given pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the sample dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# dictionary of lists
dict1 = {'name':["aparna", "pankaj", "sudhir", "Geeku"],
        'degree': ["MBA", "BCA", "M.Tech", "MBA"],
        'score':[90, 40, 80, 98]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

I would like to create a list of two dataframe columns in every row.
As in, I want nC2 operation on the column names and every row of the list would have two column names. Expected output list is as follows:-

```
output_list[0]=['name','degree']
output_list[1]=['score','degree']
output_list[2]=['name','score']
```

Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from  itertools import combinations

print (list(combinations(df.columns, 2)))
[('name', 'degree'), ('name', 'score'), ('degree', 'score')]

output_list = [list(x) for x in combinations(df.columns, 2)]
print(output_list)
[['name', 'degree'], ['name', 'score'], ['degree', 'score']]


output_list = list(map(list, combinations(df.columns, 2)))
print(output_list)
[['name', 'degree'], ['name', 'score'], ['degree', 'score']]
```

Comment: combinations is a package?

Comment: @MacroPanda - it is part of `itertools`, added import to answer.